# "FOR" command for a specific file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Seems like I can use the `FOR` command recursively to search for wildcards such as

`FOR /R %F IN (*.ASM) DO @ECHO %F`

This successfully prints out all files with the .ASM extension that exist somewhere within the current directory tree

However, if I'm searching for a specific filename, this doesn't work at all:

`FOR /R %F IN (LECTURE3_CODE.ASM) DO @ECHO %F`

The output of the latter command seems to print out `<path>\LECTURE3_CODE.ASM` once for *every single file that exists in the working directory tree*.

Is there some way to get this command to work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple:

```
FOR /R %f IN (*.ASM) DO (if "%~nf"=="LECTURE3_CODE" ECHO %f)
```

Done!

Comment: This will be more reliable with a `/i` switch after the `if` command to accept a match in any sentence case.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your original line - the wildcard is the key here.

```
FOR /R %F IN (LECTURE3_CODE.AS?) DO @ECHO %F
```