# Make batch file FOR command work with no wildcard characters?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I've seen examples of how to use batch files that go through directories and process various files that match wildcard expressions, for example:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.ext) DO (
    ECHO Found ext file %cd%\%%f
)
```

The above will match only files ending in `.ext` in the current directory.  However what if I only want to match one exact filename, if it exists in that directory?  I want something like:

```
FOR %%f IN (someFile.ext) DO (
    ECHO Found our file name in %cd%
)
```

However this doesn't seem to work; the `FOR` command interprets "somefile.ext" as a string and always runs the `FOR` loop once.  How can I try to match that exact filename in the current directory, with no wildcard characters?

Comment: If just checking for a single file, use an `if exists` check.

Comment: Or `if exist`, as it were.  `help if` in a cmd console for more info.

Comment: `for` doesn't check the file system if a dedicated path is given; only if needed, that is, wildcards `*`, `?` are given, the file system is accessed;

Comment: This question may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395010/for-command-for-a-specific-file

Comment: @GovindParmar Interesting, I was thinking wildcard question mark in ext: `for %g in ("someFile.ex?") do echo found %~g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows needs a "wildcard" expression for the `FOR` loop to operate as expected.  So you can either provide such an expression while potentially matching extra files through the wildcard, and use an extra `IF` statement to filter them out:

```
FOR %%f IN (somefile.ext*) DO (
    IF /I "%%f"=="somefile.ext" (
        ECHO Found somefile.ext in
        ECHO dir: %cd%
        ECHO.
    )
)
```

... or just use an `IF` statement in the first place to check for the existence of the file:

```
IF EXIST somefile.ext (
    ECHO Found somefile.ext in
    ECHO dir: %cd%
    ECHO.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to change to make it work because it is working. It is just not doing what you expect it to do.

The `for` command is designed to iterate over a set of elements that don't need to be files or folders, but when one of the elements in the set include a wildcard it will be seen as a query to the filesystem and the element in the set will be replaced with the list of files/folders that match the wildcard expression.

You can include a wildcard in the expression (yes, the question said *"with no wildcard"*) to force the `for` command to check the filesystem, but there is no way to create a wildcard expression that will only match your file without the posibility of matching another one so you will need to also check that the element being processed is the required one.

```dos
for %%a in ("somefile.ext?") do if /i "%%~nxa"=="somefile.ext" (
     echo File exists
)
```

If you can not use wildcards and only execute the code if the file is present, there are some options and most of them include some problems.

If you don't need to use the modifiers of the `for` replaceable parameter, you  can simply use

```dos
if exist "somefile.ext" (
    rem your code
)
```

Or, if you need the replaceable parameter and its modifiers

```dos
for %%a in ("somefile.ext") do if exist "%%~fa" (
    rem your code
)
```

*note*: If you are not going to use variables for the file references, I like it better than `if exist "file" for %%a in ("file")`, as there is only one place with a reference to the file name)

Both options will check the filesystem for the presence of the indicated element, but both will not see the difference between a file and an folder.

So, just to be sure it exists, and it is a not a folder additional checks must be done to discard folders (also check that `somefile.ext\` does not exist), or we can use something like

```dos
(>nul 2>&1 dir /a-d "somefile.ext") && (
    echo file exists
) || (
    echo file does not exist
)
```

Or, if the `for` is needed

```dos
for %%a in ("somefile.ext") do (>nul 2>&1 dir /a-d "%%~fa") && (
    echo %%~fa exists
) || (
    echo %%~fa does not exist
)
```

In both cases a `dir` command is executed to check for the presence of the file, not a folder (`/a-d`), and conditional execution operators used to determine the code to execute.

**note**: I discarded any option that would imply having to got a read handle to the file because it could be present but not be readable.

Comment: Please could you edit your answer to add why you use `%%~fa` and `%%~nxa` rather than `%%f`?

Comment: @Jez, Supose you use a file reference with path. In the case where I use `%%~nxa` as the right part of the condition is the name and extension, I'm just checking the file name and extension no matter what `%%a` could contain. In the rest of the cases i directly use the full path to the file (`%%~fa`), just an habit of mine. I prefer to explicitly indicate the value I am using in every case. And in any case as I'm using `%%a` as the `for` replaceable parameter `%%f` has not been defined